# Unable to access custom claims in Firebase realtime database rules

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

As per the docs if I generate a custom token with custom claims, I should be able to access the custom claims as `auth.token.<claim_name>`. But I'm unable to access it in the rules. I can see the claims in the token when I decode it on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)

I created a custom token with some custom claims as below:

```
auth = async (id_token, appName, isAdmin = false) => {
    const decoded = decodeJWTToken(id_token);
    const userId = decoded.user_id;
    const additionalClaims = {
        appName: appName,
        isAdmin: isAdmin
    };
    console.log("additionalClaims: ", additionalClaims);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const auth = admin.auth();
        auth.createCustomToken(userId, additionalClaims)
            .then((customToken) => {
                // console.log("Token: ", customToken);
                return resolve({ token: customToken });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                return reject('Error creating custom token:', error);
            });
    });
}
```

Now the return custom token does show the following data when checked on [jwt.io](https://jwt.io)

```
{
  "aud": "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
  "iat": 1703816038,
  "exp": 1703819638,
  "iss": "foo@bar.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "sub": "foo@bar.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "uid": "8109310812",
  "claims": {
    "appName": "TestApp",
    "isAdmin": true
  }
}
```

But when tested get calls by passing the token as below:

```
GET 'https://my-proj-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/users/1232.json?auth=<custom_token_generated_above>'
```

& the following Firebase rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.token.isAdmin === true || auth.token.appName === 'TestApp'",
    ".write": "auth.token.isAdmin === true || auth.token.appName === 'TestApp'",
  }
}
```

it fails. Tried write too, even that fails, with multiple variations on the rules, couldn't succeed.

The response says:

```
401: Unauthorized
{
  "error" : "Permission denied"
}
```

As per all the docs, the above is supposed to work. I'm completely lost, please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen, updated the question. I was trying to bring the focus more on to the fact that I'm not able to access the claims. But yep the question shows wrong rules, hence updated it.